# Does azure pipeline 'command line' agent job inherit working directory from the previous job?

Tags: windows, azure-pipelines

My understanding about azure pipelines agent jobs was that:

1. Each job is independent
2. And that each 'command line' job runs in its own context with an independent scope.

But if the working directory of azure pipeline 'command line' is not set, then it defaults to the working directory from previous 'command line' agent job.

Answer (score 0):

Before I answer the question I want to make sure the terminology is clear:

- pipelines are the overall definition of your ci cd process, they can contain multiple stages.
- stages are phases of your pipeline, like build, test, deploy... They can contain multiple jobs.
- jobs are collections of tasks/steps needed to implement your process. They contain one or more task/step.
- tasks or steps are the actual actions being executed like "execute this command" "build that dotnet project"...

The environment is reset between each job (meaning a new virtual machine will be used, sources pulled again etc.). Between each task or step that belong to the same job, you will keep the same environment and each task will "benefit" the outcome (files changed, environment variables...) From the previous ones.
In terms of working directory, they all default to the build.workingDirectory (see azure devops default variables).
If you set the working directory of one task to something different, it will not impact other tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Microsoft-hosted agent, each time you run a pipeline, you get a fresh virtual machine. The virtual machine is discarded after one use. Each job may use different agents, you should not assume that the state from an earlier job is available during subsequent.
And follow is a simple test about it.
I create two agent job in my pipeline, and add the command task and run the agent job one by one. In first command task, I create a .txt file in $( Agent.BuildDirectory) folder and then read it.
[image]

In the second command task, I just changed to the folder and try to read the .txt file.
[image]

At last, the second task failed and show me the error message.
[image]

If I set working directory in first task, and not set it in second task. The two tasks’ working directory is different.
[image]